# Gateway error when connecting Python to Teradata

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, teradata, teradatasql

Can anyone share some information regarding the issue below? I have been able to connect to Teradata via Python using Teradata and Teradatasql libraries. I cannot connect using pyodbc and sqlalchemy.

Python code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine=create_engine('teradata://'+username+':'+password+'@'+server+'/'+database+'?driver='+driver)
conn = engine.connect()
```

Error:

```
DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (135, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (135) Neither TLS port nor Legacy Port has any response. Please check Teradata Database Gateway configurations., [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (135) Neither TLS port nor Legacy Port has any response. Please check Teradata Database Gateway configurations.')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

Comment: I think default database needs to be another keyword parameter after the `?` and you probably would be better off using `teradatasqlalchemy` package (`teradatasql` dialect prefix).

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much.